# How to access user information from view in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, access-token, security-context

How can I access to user information (security-context) from view in symfony2. Using PHP, not twig templates.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We will need to see some of the code you have tried. If you do not have any code, there are plenty of tutorials out there with a little bit of googling.

Answer (score 3):

As described in the [Global Template Variables part](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#global-template-variables) of [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html), you can access the current user within your template (using the `app` [Global Variable](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Templating/GlobalVariables.html)) as follow,

**Using PHP,**

```
<?php $app->getUser() ?>
```

**Using Twig,**

```
{{ app.user }}
```